# OCR of text and numbers of a Draws - using Tesseract and Java

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I have a little general question about OCR of draws (tables), because I want to analyze these images and extract data.
I use Java (but if you suggest other, this is not a problem) and I tried Tesseract with javacpp library with not so much luck.

Sample code used:

```
    BytePointer outText;

    TessBaseAPI api = new TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api.Init(null, "ita") != 0) {
        System.err.println("Could not initialize tesseract.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    PIX image = pixRead("image.jpg");
    api.SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api.GetUTF8Text();
    System.out.println("OCR output:\n" + outText.getString());
```

From the image uploaded I obtain only the names:

```
1) Quintavalle Gianluca - 4.NC
1) Quintavalle Gianluca - 4.NC
Barelli Paolo - 4NC :
```

I think the problem is the particular layout because the image is very clear, but I need to find out event the results (60 61).

I tried a lot of different draws and different Tesseract options and pagesegmode but I couldn't get the data needed.

[image: img1]

My final purpose is to obtain from the draws a list of matches:

```
- winner1- loser1- result1 
- winner2- loser2- result2
etc
```

from a draws like this:
[image: img2]

Thanks a lot for all the help, it's for a research project.